# Is it possible to transform a js string into a date to upload it to a SQL database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

so I'm working on a bot and I'm trying to make it upload two dates but the arguments I can have are numbers (that are in a string). So I have two strings, for example, '08222020' and '10282022' and I need to transform them into a date so I am able to insert it into my database.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the string first

```
let d = '08222020';
d = d.slice(0, 2) + '/' + d.slice(2, 4) + '/' + d.slice(4, 8);
new Date(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
new Date(string);
```

Comment: that would return Invalid Date, since the string is not formatted properly

Comment: Hey, thank you for your fast response! It tells me it's an invalid date. I declared the variable with var finishingDate = new Date(args[3]);
args[3] equals 08222020

Comment: Look at Finn Lyonn's answer to convert the date to something parsable.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the string into a object to have more "customizability". You can have your own date formats. As it's an object, you can add, remove or manipulate any properties.

```
function convertToDate(date) {
    
var arr = date.match(/.{2,2}/g);
let obj = {};
  
for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
        obj.date = arr[i]
    } 
    if(i == 1) {
        obj.month = arr[i]
    } 
    if(i == 3) {
        obj.year = "20" + arr[i] //I supp
    } 
    
}
return JSON.stringify(obj)
}
    
var b = convertToDate("20062045")
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Tomas and welcome to SO.

```
var date =  '08222020';
date = Number.parseInt(date);
const d = new Date(date);

var year  = d.getUTCFullYear();
var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day   = d.getUTCDate();

//the right format for mysql
month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
day   = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
date  = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

console.log(year);
console.log(month);
console.log(day);
console.log(date);

//output
1970
"01"
"01"
"1970-01-01"
```

Comment: No problem Tomas

Answer (score -2):

As you describe your problem.

Yes, it can be done.

Using `new Date()`

eg:

```
new Date(Number('08222020')) // to convert into date
```

use `new Date(08222020).getDay()` to get Day, Month ,Year etc.

Comment: this returns Thursday, 1st January 1970. Not quite accurate

Comment: furthur  use new Date(08222020).getDay() //for day new Date(08222020).getMonth() //for month and new Date(08222020).getYear() //for Year